# Shopify .NET App Webhooks

Tags: .net, shopify

Building my first shopify app using .net 4.  The app is a fulfillment service and will provide some end points for the shopify webhooks to call.

I have built a sample app on my local machine which is working with my dev shop.  I can authenticate, add a new fulfillment service and subscribe to webhook events via the API.

What I'm struggling with is how the app will work in the real world, ie when one or more shop owners install it.

1. When it's first installed I would need to call the API to add a fulfillment service and add the webhooks. when/where would I do this? Is there a app installed webhook or similar. As this only needs to be called once
2. If I have a webhook that is used by more than one shop, how do I verify an incoming post to determine which shop the post came from.

Appreciate any help with these last pieces to the puzzle

Thanks